# Can I have fast indication on text input field to show on which language i'm currently typing?

Tags: windows, language, api

On my daily work with Windows 8, I use language input switching very often (using Alt+Shift) and every now and then when I type in language A I forget I switched to B on the previous application.  Because I'm focused on my typing and I type a lot, I notice I'm using the wrong input language after a few seconds of typing.

This can happen tens of times a day, and it's very irritating.

Is there a way to indicate what language input I'm currently using within the text field I'm currently typing, before I type anything?

Comment: Please edit the question to add what application(s) you're using, which might drive what solutions are available.